# Laravel choses wrong queue connection

Tags: laravel, supervisord

I've been developing a system for about 2 months now without any problems. However, now when it's time for launch, I did setup a dedicated server and started installing everything that was needed. However, when I came to settung up supervisor, things got ugly.

In my .env file I got this setting:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

However, when starting supervisor, I get this error:

```
{
"class": "Error",
"message": "Class 'Aws\\Sqs\\SqsClient' not found",
"code": 0,
"file": "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Connectors/SqsConnector.php:26",
"trace": [
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php:157",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php:138",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:145",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php:116",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php:100",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:40",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:93",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:37",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:610",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:136",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:121",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:971",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:290",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:166",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:93",
    "/var/www/brevia-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:129",
    "
```

I've tried to do cache:clear and config:clear, but still the worker thinks that I want to run the SqsQueue and not the database-queue... Tried looking around but can't find anyone with a similar problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and PHP 7.3.26

EDIT

Running the command:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

works, so the problem might be the supervisor setup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. When I started the supervisor it turns out that I had put the wrong flag by misstake. This forced the worker to run AWS instead of the setting in the .env

Comment: Can you write which flag you used before and which fixed it? I might have similar problem

Comment: Hey @LukasGrofcik! The command my supervisor is running atm is: php /var/www/myapp/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600 --timeout=10, that's it :)

Answer (score 2):

Add to .env
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

And add fix the construction in config file ~/config/queue.php to

```
[
    'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),
     ....
      ....
]
```

Comment: The weird thing is that Laravel still targets the Ses for some reason... I still get the same error "Class 'Aws\Sqs\SqsClient' not found" even after config:clear & config:cache... Seems like there is some other setting that I forgot about

Comment: If I run "php artisan queue:work" manually, it works fine. So seems like there is something wrong when supervisor tries to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue, and just realized the config I copied directly from Laravel's Queue documentation had **sqs** as a php artisan parameter

> command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3
> --tries=3 --max-time=3600

I did change the artisan location, but somehow the sqs parameter escaped me.

I just removed it and the worker ran just as expected.